# How to return the "string" value (as a string) for a property from each object in an array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have an array of 2 objects `[{...},{...}]`. Each object has 5 properties with key:value

```
consent: true
id: "00c3e7ab-7411-4c52-87e0-01779cd658ad"
idConfirmed: true
label: "test_Label"
presignedURL: "https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/......./..."
```

[Array Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ufSJ.png)

I want to use this array as the 'data' for my React-Table and render (as a string) the presigned URL for each array item. I need this to be String because I want to wrap this is an 'a' tag to direct to the presignedURL. I can get everyting rendering fine, just as I want, but the PreseignedURL values are of type Object and not string, therefore I am unable to direct my  tag where I want.

[pointing to localhost:3000//[object Object] instead of the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnJhs.png)

**What I have done so far:**

I have tried to render Cell content .toString(), but this has no effect

```
<a href={cell.render('Cell'.toString())}>{(cell.render('Cell'))}<br /></a>
```

I have also tried converting the presignedURL values from the intial object array to an array of Strings, `const stringArr = initialArr.map(({ presignedURL }) => presignedURL)` but then I don't think I can use react table to display this array as React-table(as I understand it) requires a key/value couple so that the key can be used as the accessor:

Basically, I need to know how, and if it is possible to render cell contents, as type String using react-Table?

Full code for component:

```
const ReviewRounds = () => {

 const[rounds, setRounds]=useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{
  fetchVids();
},[]) 

const fetchVids=async()=>{
   
  await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_All_ROUNDS)
   .then(res=>{
     console.log("Response:", res.data)
     setRounds(res.data)
 });
};

   //Table Cols
   const columns = React.useMemo(
    ()=>[
    {
      Header:"Videos",
      accessor: "presignedURL"
    },
  ],
  []
  )

  const{
    getTableProps,
     getTableBodyProps,
     headerGroups,
     rows,
     prepareRow,
  } =useTable({columns , data:rounds})

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                style={{
                  borderBottom: 'solid 3px blue',
                  background: 'aliceblue',
                  color: 'black',
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  fontSize:'28px'
                }}
              >
                {column.render('Header')}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map(row => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return (
                  <td
                    {...cell.getCellProps()}
                    style={{
                      padding: '10px',
                      border: 'solid 1px gray',
                      background: 'aliceblue',
                    }}
                  >
                    <a href={cell.render('Cell'.toString())}>{(cell.render('Cell'))}<br /><img src={hospital}/></a>
                  </td>
                )
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
      }
      export default ReviewRounds;
```

Comment: Please show how you're getting these values into the Cell object.

Comment: @samuei I have attached entire component code to original post for context